# Apache virtual hosts, aliasing, and directories

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, directory

If you have an Apache running at `somewhere.net`, and you have a number of virtual hosts as well (`a.somewhere.net`, `b.somewhere.net`), you can access directories on the main branch while you are on the virtual hosts.

For instance, let's say I install [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). I can access it, after including the `apache.conf` file, by going to `somewhere.net/phpmyadmin`. However, I can also access it by going to `a.somewhere.net/phpmyadmin` or `b.somewhere.net/phpmyadmin`. I assume this has to do with the line `Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin` (in `phpmyadmin`'s `apache.conf`), and that it applies to all virtual hosts on `Apache`.

Is there a way to make it just apply to the default site, and none of the subdomains?
Can I make it so `a.something.net/phpmyadmin` won't find `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: Where did you configure that `Alias` line?

Comment: It is in the generated `phpmyadmin` `apache.conf` file (which is included in apache's `apache2.conf`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move that `Alias` directive (and possibly other parts of the generated config?) or the `Include` that's bringing in the phpmyadmin config into the specific `<VirtualHost>` blocks that you want it to apply to - that will cause them to apply only to those specific virtual hosts instead of the entire server.

Comment: Should I just move the `Include` of the `phpmyadmin` `apache.conf` from apache's `apache2.conf` to the specific virtual host?

Comment: @MirroredFate Yup, that will work too!

Comment: Tried it, it didn't D: I tried moving the include directive to a couple different virtual host configuration files, but it is still available no matter which subdomain I use. Will keep looking for something out of place.

Comment: @MirroredFate That's.. strange.  Does it go away if you turn off the `Include` in the one virtual host?

Comment: Yes, it goes away completely. It can no longer be found by Apache anywhere.

Comment: It is working now. I don't know why. Possibly caching of some sort. Thanks. Do you think you could edit your answer to mention moving the `Include` directive the the appropriate virtual host?

Comment: @MirroredFate Great!  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

remove the alias from the conf.

```
ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /$vHostDocRoot/phpmyadmin
```

that is the easiest way.... other wise you can try moving the `Alias` directive into the virtual host configuration.